# How do I configure the reset password in laravel

Tags: laravel

I recently hosted my website to the live server but i'm not sure how to change the credentials in my .env file for it to work on the live server.

Comment: what type of error is shown in browser??

Comment: No error.Its going to mailtrap.io.How do I make it go to the designated email ID.

Answer (score 0):

you just need to create mail account on your server and go to mail setting of your server 
you will found outgoing server url , username and password which you need to replace in .env file

Comment: Thank you but now im getting this error - Swift_TransportException
Connection to webcloud4.uk.syrahost.com:465 Timed Out

Comment: try sendmail, smtp one by one as driver in env file

Comment: I did try it and i'm getting the same problem

Comment: right now use https://mailtrap.io/  details and update me what's happen